# Is It Possible To Modify an EXE to run on startup?

Tags: windows

This is a program called [Windows Enabler](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Windows-Enabler.shtml) which runs in the taskbar and let's you click on some grayed out buttons in software, problem is you have to manually click on it in the taskbar so it says ON for it to do its thing. Is there a way to add a prompt or something to the exe so it does so automatically?

Comment: Sure. Open an explorer window, click in an empty space in the addressbar so you can type, and replace the text with `shell:startup` and press enter. In the new location, place a shortcut to the exe and it will start at startup. This and many other ways can be googled. Its not secret information.

Comment: The title is misleading. The question is about setting a piece of running software to an "enabled/active" state when it is programmed to start in a "disabled/inactive" state.

Comment: depends entirely on whether the application offers you a configuration option to do that.

Comment: No, there is no way.  I used this app in 1998.  It is VERY old.  If it were ON all of the time, it would be bad.  There is a reason it was designed the way it was.  Also, won't work on many modern controls.